# Windows 8 on MSI Windpad 110W has little to no free memory after waking from sleep

Tags: windows-8, memory, sleep, tablet

I have an MSI WindPad 110W that I bought new (not used) with 4 GB of memory installed and about 256 MB reserved for video. I did a clean install of Windows 8 on it and have since been using it.

After going to sleep (either automatically or manually) and being woken up I notice the memory (shown in Task Manager) is usually upwards of 80 or 90 % used. Usually there is one Metro/Windows Store app running, the Reader app that comes preinstalled with Windows and sometimes Firefox. Looking in Task Manager I do not see anything taking up the several gigabytes of memory Windows claims is in use. Is there something I should look further at or into to see what the cause is?

**UPDATE:**

Here is Task Manager showing the problem. Note that 92% is about 3 GB and the highest process use is 37 MB by Explorer.
[image: Task Manager showing the problem: High memory usage in total, but nothing really taking up memory]

A second image, this one of the Performance tab:
[image: Screenshot of the Performance tab in Task Manager]

Finally, someone suggested Performance Monitor. This is what it shows:

[image: Resource Monitor showing memory usage]

Again, if anyone can help me correct this problem, or even help me confirm it is an actual bug in some software or Windows itself so I can stop using it/file a bug report, I'll be happy.

Comment: Could be a driver bug... Make sure to get all the updated drivers from th manufacturer's website. Additionally, get Process Explorer and enable the Virtual Size column, that will give you a better idea of what the culprit might be.

Comment: OK, I've downloaded and configured it. I will report back when this happens again.

Comment: Right-click the column category bar, then you can select whichever metrics you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non page memory leak. This is a driver issue. To resolve it, do the following:

- install the [WDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/)
- open the command prompt with admin rights in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Tools\x64
- run the tool **poolmon.exe**, press **B** to sort per Bytes.
- find the raw with the highest Bytes

[image]

(Image source: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316190149/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ntdebugging/))

- look at the "Tag" Column and remember those 4 characters.
- open the command prompt in C:\Windows\System32\drivers and run this command

  **findstr /s those_4_characters *.sys**
- look which drivers are shown, look at the file versions and make sure they are all update to date. if not, update them.

Comment: The file that that turns up is spaceport.sys, which appears to be a part of Windows 8. Should I post a new thread about how to "fix" this, or refactor my question?

Comment: spaceport.sys is the new Storage Spaces‎ feature. Do you use it?

Comment: No. This machine has 1 HD and no others.

Comment: Contact the MS support about the isue. This looks like a bug in Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Resource monitor would be of help there - you can access this through a link in task manager

[image]

This will give you a breakdown of memory usage per app, and how memory is being used.

Some things to note - with memory on resource monitor, the green part is what you really need to worry about. 'standby memory' is basicallly stuff cached for faster use.

Comment: I will do this when I experience the problem again.

Comment: OK, I've reproduced the problem and have posted the screenshots.