# Windows 7 having high physical memory usage, how to reduce it?

Tags: windows-7, memory, vmware-workstation, memory-leaks

1. This is a pro active question, right now I am not facing any problem, thou it may create a problem anytime 
   which I just can't afford.
2. I am using VMware® Workstation - version - 8.0.1 build-528992
3. I am also running one VM on it. details of that VM are listed below:
   DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
   ---Hardware Assigned to VM:
   CPU : 2
   Cores per CPU : 2
   RAM : 3 GB
   Virtual HDD : 20 GB
4. For physical Machine info Please go through below info and Screenshot.
   C Drive : Total 160 GB / Used 84 GB / Free 76 GB
   D Drive : Total 728 GB / Used 457 GB / Free 271 GB

[image]

5. Screenshot of Task Manager Performance:

[image]

6. Screenshot of Task Manager Processes:
   Processes are sort as per the memory usage.

[image]

7. Antivirus Version:
   [image]

[image]

Let me know if you need any further help from my side and Please help me resolve the high physical memory uasage issue. Thanks in advance.

Here is the requested screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Do you still see all that memory utilized if you shutdown VM, quit Chrome and stop McAfee AV?

Comment: Enable Commit Size column on Task Manager's process tab (or just the screenshot from Memory Tab on Resource Monitor)

Comment: Yes I do see high physical memory usage even if I quit chrome. However I have my e-mail server which is on VM & McAfee is required to secure the Internet and LAN, as this is a live server VM. thou high memory usage was not there before 2-3 days as this system was ruining VM and McAfee at that time also. and at that time it use to show good memory usage of 5 GB around avg. So there must be some problem I think which is causing this high memory usage issue... ??

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo please check my comment and have added one more screenshot with  Commit Size column in Task Manager's process tab. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Windows assumes that physical memory has no cost associated with using it. It makes no effort whatsoever to make physical memory free because this makes no sense. If it makes physical memory free, only one of two things can happen:

1. That memory isn't used any time soon. In this case, the effort of making it free was wasted.
2. That memory is used soon. In this case, the effort of making it free was harmful, as now the system simply has to undo that work to use the memory.

Modern operating systems only make physical memory free if they have absolutely no other possible choice.

If you're thinking "I need memory free *now* so I can use it later", forget it. You can use memory now *and* use it later. There's no painful tradeoff that you have to make here.

Everything is fine.

If you want a more detailed understanding of how physical memory is being used on your system, try [RAMMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx).

Comment: nothing is fine with his system. He has a memory leak caused by a driver ;)

Comment: @David Schwartz May I request you to please give me some source of information to support your replay. I would like to go ahead and read that. Request you to please do not take it otherwise, as I do not mean to offend you or your statements.

Comment: @Rishee: You can read up on memory management anywhere. One site that tries to explain this from a commonsense angle (it's Linux specific, but the concepts are the same) is [linuxatemyram](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/). (But really, what I presented above is a reasoned argument. No source is needed. All its premises should be obviously true. For example, on typical systems Windows run on, using RAM has no cost. So it's logical Windows would understand this. And so on.)

Comment: @David Schwartz Thanks a lot!! It was very useful & Comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a driver which doesn't free the memory (6GB of non paged pool). You must run `poolmon` from the `WDK` to see the causing driver. I've already posted the steps here:

[Windows 8 on MSI Windpad 110W has little to no free memory after waking from sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/526573/windows-8-on-msi-windpad-110w-has-little-to-no-free-memory-after-waking-from-sle/538208#538208)

Comment: Hi... I have followed the steps you said but the result of last step is not in human readable format... :( . what should I do now?

Comment: When I said last command I meant result of below command.                                `findstr /s those_4_characters *.sys`

Comment: @Rishee upload the sorted poolmon picture so that I can see the tag.

Comment: @Rishee is the issue fixed or not?